# Q&A: Determine if a tranformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

The goal is to prove if a transformation is linear.

$$\tag{1} T_1(x,y) = (x-2y, \cos x), T_1:R^2 \to R^2$$
$$\tag{2} T_3(z_1,z_2) = z_1+ \bar{z}_2, T_3:C^2 \to C$$

---

If $T$ satisfies:
$$
\forall a \in R, \forall v \in R^2:T(av) = aT(v) \\
\forall v,u \in R^2: T(v+u) = T(v) + T(u)
$$
So $T$ is a linear transformation.

We will check that on $T_1$, $T_3$

On $T_3$ check when:
$\tag{a} T_3 \ on \ \Bbb R$ 
$\tag{b} T_3 \ on \ \Bbb C $

---

Answer (score 0):

*If you see any mistake/better way please correct me.

### My attempt

$T_1$:

$v = (x,y), a\in R \Rightarrow av = (ax,ay)$

$\Rightarrow T(av) = T(ax,ay) = (a(x-2y),cos(ax))$

$\Rightarrow aT(v) = aT(x,y) = (a(x-2y),acos(x))$

$\exists a \in R: acos(x) \neq cos(ax) \Rightarrow T_1$ is not a linear transformation.

$T_3$:

$v = (z_1,z_2), u=(z_3,z_4)$

$\Rightarrow T(v+u) = T(z_1+z_3, z_2+z_4) = (z_1+z_3) + (\overline{z_2+z_4}) = z_1+z_3 + \bar{z}_2+\bar{z}_4$

$\Rightarrow T(v)+T(u) = T(z_1,z_2) + T(z_3,z_4) = z_1 + \overline{z_2} + z_3 + \overline{z_4}$

$$
\Downarrow \\
T(v+u) = T(v) + T(u)
$$

$a \in R$ or $a \in C$

$\Rightarrow aT(v) = aT(z_1,z_2) = a(z_1 + \overline{z_2}) = az_1 + a\overline{z_2}$

$\Rightarrow T(av) = T(az_1,az_2) = az_1 + \overline{az_2}$

if $a \in R: \overline{az_2} = a\overline{z_2} \Rightarrow aT(v) = T(av)$

if $a \in C:  $ Let $a = i$, $\overline{az_2} = -a\overline{z_2} \Rightarrow aT(v) \neq T(av)$

$\Rightarrow T_3$ is not a linear transformation.